# How to show different Detail page layout of a custom object on the basis of User's Profile's Field's value in salesforce

Tags: apex, visualforce, page-layout

I have two layouts for a custom object i.e. "**Company__c**". Now I wan to use a layout according to the selection of a pick-list value in user profile i.e. System Administrator.
Lets say I have two layouts named as **Layout_1** and **Layout_2**, such both layouts have different fields and sections.

And there is a pick-list field in system administrator profile having two values named as **Value1** and **Value2**. On selection of **Value1**, The object **Company__c** should use/show **Layout_1** and on selection of **Value2**, it should use/show **Layout_2**.

How can I do this?
Please help me.

Comment: Have you tried using Record Types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer for my question.
We can do it by using visualforce page layouts. i.e. the pages made by us in visualforce.

Here I queried the required field from system administrator profile, and on the basis of the value of the field, I made page-reference to the desired page. That's what I have done to solve this problem and I got my desired result. :)
I believe it will help others too.

Answer (score 0):

The detail page layout depends on the profile the user is assigned to. It can not be linked to the field value.

What you can do is to override a standard page layout with a visualforce page. You will get a full control on the look & feel of the page and additionally you can control visibility of the fields shown to certain users based on their data (eg. profile, profile field value etc.)

Comment: But for overriding a standard page with a visualforce page, I have to override all standard pages with their relative visulaforce pages. 
Am I right???

Comment: @KhawajaM.Awais You can have only one overridden page layout for all profiles, and do layout validation inside the visualforce page based on the current user settings (profile/field/etc)